# Does React.memo create a singleton component or can it be used to create multiple independent instances

Tags: reactjs, performance, memoization

When wrapping a component function in React.memo, is the result a singleton (similar to reselect's createSelector method), meaning that it's primarily designed for a single instance?  Or does each reference to the resulting memoized component create its own separate memoized instance?

Example: Is this a valid use of React.memo?

```
const Item = React.memo((props) => <li>...</li>);

// App
render(): {
  const { items } = this.props
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => <Item {...item} />)}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can render as many `Item`s as you want. The memoization is per instance.

Comment: React.memo will not return a memoized function so you can't do `Item(props)` anymore.